# Query two collections by referenced field using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Good day coders,

**I WANT TO ACHIEVE THIS**

I don't want to repeat field data in my collection field object so I decided to store the parent collection field(foreign key) as keys in the child collection as an object field, meaning each object field of the child collection is referencing a key field in parent collection.

**PRESENT CHALLENGE**

My question is how I would query details of each of this reference object field in child collection to their parent collection using mongoose. See example below:

```
const classSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String },
    role: { type: String, enum: ["user", "admin"], default: "user" },
    status: { type: String, enum: ["active", "blocked"], default: "active" },
    collections: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Collection" }],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);


const sportSchema = new Schema(
  {
    sport: { type: String },
    level: { type: String },
    usersReference: [{ type: Object }],       
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

**MONGOOSE NODEJS**

/* I am stuck here because I am a NodeJS MySQL person for years, i would rather join this tables from 
as a View from MySQL and just query it as a table here but lately I have developed interest in NOSQL*/

const studentSportDetails = studentSportDetails.find({})
```

The focus is on the `sportSchema` where I have a `usersReference` field that expects 3 different users from the classSchema i.e. sport captain, assistant, and reserved captain. These are the objects that will be in the `usersReference` field. My concern is I want to query the `sportSchema` collection and I want to join the "username, email and role" from `classSchema` using the `usersReference` object field. Each field in the "usersReference object Field" in the `sportSchema` is referenced in the classSchema.

I started using Mongoose with mongo not quite long and I am stuck here.

Please can somebody advise how to achieve this? I appreciate your efforts in advance.